# Array_Push() Correctly

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
$foundNumbers   = array('number' => 'userId');
```

For each entry in the database I want to push the array:

```
    {
        $foundNumbers[]->number = $number;
        $foundNumbers[]->userId = $row['userId'];
    }
```

But this one doesn't work.
How can I push the array with $number to number and $row['userId'] to userid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have older php version you can do it like this:

```
$foundNumbers[] = array('number' => $number, 'userId' => $userId);
```

however in the php5.4 and above you can use the short array syntax

```
$foundNumbers[] = ['number' => $number, 'userId' => $userId];
```